# pygameでインスタンス生成時に引数として、何故selfを指定しているのか分かりません

Tags: python, pygame

Python初学者です。参考書にて基礎から学びつつ、応用としてpygameを使った学習を行っています。

メインモジュール内でShipクラスのインスタンス生成時にShip()の引数として、何故selfを指定しているのか分かりません。これまで進めてきた参考書にも記載は無く、他にもネットなどで調べてみても（私の調べ方の問題もあると思っています。）分かりませんでした。お分かりになる方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教授いただければ幸いです。

メインモジュール

```
import sys

import pygame

from settings import Settings

from ship import Ship

class AlienInvasion:
    """overall class to manage game assets and behavior."""
    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the game, and create game resources."""
        pygame.init()

        self.settings = Settings()

        """To create a display window"""
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
            (self.settings.screen_width, self.settings.screen_height))

        pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

        ## ** This is where I am confused about!!!!
        self.ship = Ship(self)

    def run_game(self):
        """Start the main loop of the game"""
        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit()

            self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)

            self.ship.blitme()

            pygame.display.flip()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ai = AlienInvasion()
    ai.run_game()
```

settings.pyモジュール

```
class Settings:
    """A class to stroe all settings for Alien Invasion"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.screen_width = 900
        self.screen_height = 600
        self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)
```

ship.pyモジュール

```
import pygame

class Ship:
    """A class to manage the ship."""
    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        """Initialize the ship and set its starting position."""

        self.screen = ai_game.screen

        self.screen_rect = ai_game.screen.get_rect()

        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/ship.bmp')

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.rect.midbottom = self.screen_rect.midbottom

    def blitme(self):
        """Draw the ship at its current location."""
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

Answer (score 1):

**コメント対応で更新**

済みませんね。質問を良く見ていませんでした。
**メインモジュール内でShipクラスのインスタンス生成時にShip()の引数として、何故selfを指定しているのか分からず。**

これについては、`self.ship = Ship(self)`の`Ship(self)`の **self** は、`class Ship:`の`def __init__(self, ai_game):`に渡される2つ目の引数 **ai_game** になります。

`class Settings:`の`def __init__(self):`には self 以外の引数は無いので`Settings`のインスタンスを作成する`self.settings = Settings()`には引数指定は無いですが、`class Ship:`の`def __init__(self, ai_game):`には2つ目の引数 ai_game があり、`ship`のインスタンスを作成するためには`class AlienInvasion:`のインスタンスをそこに指定する必要があるため、`Ship(self)`という呼び出し方になっている訳です。

---

**以下は回答としてはちょっと的外れな 引数 self がどういう物かの解説**

`Pygame`に依存したものでは無く、`Python`自身の仕様と習慣的な使い方ですね。

ちょっと説明不足な感じですが、Pythonのドキュメントには以下のように書かれています。
[9. クラス](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/tutorial/classes.html)
[9.4. いろいろな注意点](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/tutorial/classes.html#random-remarks)

> よく、メソッドの最初の引数を`self`と呼びます。この名前付けは単なる慣習でしかありません。`self`という名前は、 Python では何ら特殊な意味を持ちません。とはいえ、この慣行に従わないと、コードは他の Python プログラマにとってやや読みにくいものとなります。また、 クラスブラウザ (class browser) プログラムがこの慣行をあてにして書かれているかもしれません。
> メソッドは、`self`引数のメソッド属性を使って、他のメソッドを呼び出すことができます:

この説明では`self`という名前付けは習慣であって、実は何でも良いように書かれていますが、`最初の引数`が何であるかは明確には書かれていません。

Pythonのclassに属するメソッドを定義する際の最初の引数は自分自身のインスタンスをあらわしています。

他のオブジェクト指向言語では`this`と呼ばれるものと同じです。
こちらの記事が多数の言語について説明していて分かりやすいでしょう。
[this (プログラミング) - Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/This_(%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A9%E3%83%9F%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0))

> `this`は、プログラミング言語に出てくる概念のひとつで、自身の動いているオブジェクトを指す予約語。主にインスタンスメソッド内で使用される。`this`の他に`self`、`Me`といった語を使う言語もあるが、...(以下省略)

> **Python**
> Python では、`this`は文法上の予約語ではないが、自動的に対象となるオブジェクトが渡される、メンバ関数の1つ目の引数となっている。慣習的に、この引数の名前として`self`が使われる。

---

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。Pythonのドキュメントの記載を確認しつつ、引数を指定せずインスタンス生成してその後クラス内にアクセスする場合（例えばself.settings = Settings()）と、selfを引数にインスタンス生成した場合（例えばself.ship = Ship(self)）の違いについて良く分からず。self指定の場合はこの記載のように明示的にオブジェクト指定せずに自動的に指定されると、とらえれば良いのでしょうか「自動的に対象となるオブジェクトが渡される、メンバ関数の1つ目の引数となっている。」

Comment: ありがとうございます！いただきました回答内容をふまえ、自分でいろいろ試してみて理解することができました。

Answer (score 0):

selfというのはそのクラス自身を指す変数です。
例えば、AlienInvasionクラスでは、
作成されたAlienInvasionクラスにselfを使って
値を格納しています。
おそらく、Pythonを使ったオブジェクト指向プログラミングについて
学習しなかったのではないかと思います。

Comment: コメントいただきありがとうございます。ご指摘の通り、あまり学習出来ていないと思いますので改めて学習いたします。初歩的な質問ですみません。